# What are different rig types mean?

Tags: skeletal-animation, rigging

I think I know what is rig - it's a set of bones for animation. But recently I watched a presentation where the guy mentioned **animation rig**, **mesh rig**, **dynamic rig**. What each mean?

Comment: ***rig** - an apparatus, device, or piece of equipment designed for a particular purpose*. As in, people will use these differently, but they're generally tools, code, whatever used to help in the management/handling/movement/whatever for animation, meshes, whatever.

Comment: In the presentation I mentioned all this rigs were applied to one character. And after some search I agree with you that this terminology is used inside a company but not widely spread.